# Laravel 4 - How do I end up passing data to a Model function as a argument

Tags: php, laravel, parameter-passing

I have a Laravel Model called Questions, I have a many to many function that correctly outputs the Answers depending on the Question ID. I can filter the Answers outputted by using a where method to check for correct = 1 and where IDs isn't in array.

This works as expected

```
<?php 
class Questions extends Eloquent {
 public function getCorrectanswerType() {
        return $query->belongsToMany('answerTypes', 'que_ant_relationship', 'que_question_id', 'que_ant_answer_type_id')->where('que_ant_correct_answer','=','1')->whereNotIn('que_ant_answer_type_id', array(1));
    }
}

$test =  $transactionAnswers->getCorrectanswerType()->get();

?>
```

The problem is when I try to pass parameters into the function, I have to pass the data into the function because it could be different IDs. What I am trying to achieve

```
<?php

  class Questions extends Eloquent {

 public function getCorrectanswerType($ids) {
        return $query->belongsToMany('answerTypes', 'que_ant_relationship', 'que_question_id', 'que_ant_answer_type_id')->where('que_ant_correct_answer','=','1')->whereNotIn('que_ant_answer_type_id', $ids);
    }
}
$transactions = array(filled with ids)
$test =  $transactionAnswers->getCorrectanswerType($transactions)->get(); 

?>
```

But this dosent work.

Any ideas, examples, tips to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You can just do this when you call the method.

Comment: @ShayneStatzell please show an example of this, I have called the method on mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$transactionAnswers->getCorrectanswerType->WhereNotIn('que_ant_answer_type_id',$ids)->get();
```

Comment: You have it wrong, this is dynamic property call (no `()`) and it will throw error.

Answer (score 1):

1 Don't use variable conditions on relation definition:

```
class Questions extends Eloquent {
  public function correctAnswers() {
        return $query->belongsToMany('answerTypes', 'que_ant_relationship', 'que_question_id', 'que_ant_answer_type_id')->where('que_ant_correct_answer','=','1');
  }
}
```

but add those conditions eg. like this:

```
$question->correctAnswers()->whereNoIn('some_field', $somArray)->get();
```

2 Use scopes for this:

```
// AnswerType model
public function scopeExcludeTypes($query, $typeIds)
{
   $query->whereNotIn('some_field', (array) $typeIds);
}
```

then you simply do this:

```
$question->correctAnswers()->excludeTypes($someArray)->get();
```

Comment: I am busy at the moment, but I will try this out and get back to you.